# Apache Tomcat rewrite

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, tomcat

What I'm trying to do is setup a rewrite rule so that when a URL is entered it will be displayed as `example.com/test`.

So for example, I'm trying to do this if it's even possible.

I've set the CNAME of `site.example.com` to point to `site.devexample.com` (dev Remote Environment on the vendors side)

If a user visits `site.example.com` the URL will be re-written to something along these lines `example.com/test`.

What I have so far but doesn't seem to be working, when I visit `site.example.com` it stays as is.

```
# rewrite rules for site.example.com
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^site\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.site\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule $ http://example.com/test/ [R,L]
```

Will I need to do a reverse proxy and then re-write from there?

EDIT: I apologize, i should have explained a little better. site.example.com is owned by test.com (company A). So we changed the CNAME to point to site.devEnvironment.com ( companyB.com )

and test.com/test is our server and dir, trying to rewrite the URL to be test.com/test instead of site.example.com

Our redirects are setup in httpd.conf file, not sure if this will help also

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any kind of "reverse proxy", since you appear to want to "redirect" (ie. change) the URL. To clarify, `site.example.com` is being accepted by your site? Is `.htaccess` / mod_rewrite enabled? Presumably you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? ie. `RewriteEngine`?

Comment: "I'm trying to do this if it's even possible." - What you are trying to do sounds like a simple redirect, so I'm kinda wondering why you might think this is not possible or why you think you would need a "reverse proxy"? Is there something more to this question...?

Comment: "Our redirects are setup in httpd.conf file" - why is the question tagged `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess the rewritecond or rewritemap regex isn't matching.  I've found those to be slippery.

Make sure you have very verbose mod_rewrite logging (apache 2.4 set [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging), apache 2.2 set [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog))  If you are not an admin of the web server, this probably won't help you.

Try a rewriterule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^foobar /clams/%{HTTP_HOST}/fish [R,L]
```

Since `foobar` is a nonsense location, it won't interfere with real traffic.  Point your browser to `foobar` and it will redirect to another nonsense location and give you a an error, but the URL bar will also tell you exactly what the `%{HTTP_HOST}` var contains.  (The clams and fish are to act as quotes so if the `%{HTTP_HOST}` contains a slash or whitespace other tricky character, you'll see it.)

(removed / from foobar for .htaccess compatibility, thnx @w3dk)

Comment: When you specify an absolute URL (scheme + hostname) in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ mod_rewrite will implicitly trigger an external redirect, whether you include the `R` flag or not. So, there would seem to be something else going on here.

Comment: @w3dk - Nice catch!

Comment: Since the question is tagged `.htaccess` I guess this is in .htaccess, so you'll need to remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` _pattern_.

Comment: @w3dk - you continue to be awesome

Comment: Hi Dylan, Thank you for your advice I have tried your suggestion but still not working as expected

Comment: @POPEYE1716 So, what is the value of `%{HTTP_HOST}` using Dylan's example redirect? (You might need to put the slash prefix back in if your "redirects are setup in httpd.conf file" - from your updated question.)

Comment: Why leave the "OLD, INCORRECT SUGGESTION"? People can always look at the edit history...

Comment: Good point.  Removed.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is setting up a proxypass /test site.example.com

So that when the server sees /test it will load the content from site.example.com